# Server Setup for Rails 7 app with nginx and puma

Tags: nginx, webserver, puma, ruby-on-rails-7

I am really new to server configuration. I have a rails application locally and I have access to an amazon EC2 server instance. I am required to use nginx for web server and puma for application server. Can someone kindly explain to me in detail (file creation, directory, command etc) how I can make that application up and running for public access via the domain?

My rails app directories are:

```
$~ server/user/home/apps/myapp/shared/...
$~ server/user/home/apps/myapp/current/...
```

I have tried capistrano. But no matter which ever tutorial I follow, I always end up having `.../shared/tmp/sockets/puma.myapp.sock failed (2: No such file or directory) while connecting to upstream...` error.

Comment: Maybe your question is better aimed to [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0):

here are the steps that worked for me:

### Install Nginx

1. `sudo apt install nginx`
2. `sudo ufw app list`
3. `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'`

### Setup Server

1. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/appname`.
2. Copy the following template into the file and replace `appname` with the name of your app:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    root /home/apps/myapp/public;
    server_name appname.com www.appname.com;
    index index.htm index.html;

        location ~ /.well-known {
            allow all;
        }

        location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

3. `sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/repuestosgonnet /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`
4. `sudo nano /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
5. Uncomment this line: `server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;`
6. Optional: Uncomment this line: `server_tokens off;`
7. Test syntax: `sudo nginx -t`
8. Restart Nginx: `sudo systemctl restart nginx`

I hope that works for you!

Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create 2 systemd service files so that it launches puma for you:

*appname.service:*

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server for appname
After=network.target
Requires=appname.socket

[Service]
Type=simple
Environment=RAILS_ENV=production
WorkingDirectory=/user/home/apps/myapp/current/
ExecStart=/user/home/apps/.rbenv/shims/puma -e production -C /user/home/apps/myapp/shared/puma.rb /user/home/apps/myapp/current/config.ru
ExecStop=/user/home/apps/.rbenv/shims/puma -e production -C /user/home/apps/myapp/shared/puma.rb stop
ExecReload=/user/home/apps/.rbenv/shims/puma -e production -C /user/home/apps/myapp/shared/puma.rb phased-restart

PIDFile=/user/home/apps/myapp/shared/tmp/pids/puma.pid

Restart=always
RestartSec=8
KillMode=process
SyslogIdentifier=puma

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

*appname.socket:*

```
[Unit]
Description=Puma HTTP Server Accept Sockets

[Socket]
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:9294
ListenStream=0.0.0.0:9295

NoDelay=true
ReusePort=true
Backlog=1024

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Then you can relaunch systemd loader

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

And enable the files

```
systemctl enable myappli_puma_env.service myappli_puma_env.socket
```

And finally:

```
cap puma:start
```